# Compact metric space and a second countable

Tags: general-topology

Is every compact metric space meets the second countable?

Do you may have a condition equivalent? I miss just this one proof and ask for help.

Comment: Every compact metric spaceis the second countable. For a proof: http://planetmath.org/sites/default/files/texpdf/39296.pdf

Comment: For metric spaces, the properties of being second-countable, separable, and Lindelöf are all equivalent: [similar question](http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/145303/equivalence-of-three-properties-of-a-metric-space)