# Countable basis in a metric space is equivalent to being a separable metric space

Tags: real-analysis, general-topology, metric-spaces

Say we have a metric space space $(\Omega, d)$. Is the following true:

$(\Omega, d)$ has a countable basis in a metric space $\iff$  $(\Omega, d)$ separable metric space

To me the equivalence seems intuitive (in terms of open balls) but I have not seen it actually stated anywhere

Comment: https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/145303/equivalence-of-three-properties-of-a-metric-space this might be of interest

Comment: https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1810581/every-separable-metric-space-has-a-countable-base This too.

Comment: [This answer of mine](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/2812134/4280) generalises this observation considerably.