# Equivalence of countable choice for subsets of the reals and "second countable $\implies$ Lindelöf"

Tags: general-topology, axiom-of-choice

Looking for a proof that in a [second countable space](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Second-countable_space) every open cover has a countable subcover -- i.e. every s.c. space is a Lindelöf space -- I bumped into [this question](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/81216/every-open-cover-has-a-countable-subcover-lindel%c3%b6fs-lemma). That answered my question. I then left a couple of comments on both the then present answers (which are, to this date, the only ones) and received [this reply](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/81216/every-open-cover-has-a-countable-subcover-lindel%c3%b6fs-lemma/81227?noredirect=1#comment2538435_81227), stating the axiom of countable choice for subsets of the reals is actually equivalent to every s.c. space being Lindelöf. Now it seems incredible that a special case of the [axiom of countable choice](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Axiom_of_countable_choice), which in its general form states any countable collection of sets has a choice function, so for all countable collection of sets $A_n$ there is a function associating to each set an element of that set, provided of course the sets are non-empty, and in its particular form says so for sets which are subsets of the reals, be equivalent to s.c. implies Lindelöf. At most, I would expect the general form to be equivalent to that, since that s.c. implies Lindelöf is proven with a form of countable choice. So how can it be proved that the two results are equivalent?

Comment: It sounds to me like you've interpreted Brian's comment as something like CC($\Bbb R$) $\Rightarrow$ (SC$\to$L)($X$) for any topological space $X$, but it seems to me that he intended the more believable CC($\Bbb R$) $\Rightarrow$ (SC$\to$L)($\Bbb R$).

Comment: Well the comment says «I just checked: $\mathsf{}(\mathbb{R})$ is equivalent to every second countable space being Lindelöf.», so how do you read it that way?

Comment: I mean, let's break that down: $\mathsf{CC}(\mathbb{R})$ (subject) is equivalent to (predicate, in symbols $\iff$), every second countable space being Lindelöf (indirect object, which sounds terribly like $(\mathsf{SC}\implies\mathsf{L})(X)$ for any topological space $X$). What am I missing? @BrianMScott am I reading you right?

Comment: Ah, I missed "every".

Comment: @Eric: You can find this long lit of equivalences as Theorem 4.54 in Herrlich "The Axiom of Choice". I don't remember the name of the original paper, I think "disasters in topology without choice" or something similar.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This is not that incredible if you understand what's going on.

Given a second-countable space $X$, fix a countable basis $\{U_n\mid n\in\Bbb N\}$. Now you can observe that every open set is uniquely determined by the basis elements it contains, namely the function $U\mapsto\{n\in\Bbb N\mid U_n\subseteq U\}$ is an injective function. And since the real numbers can be thought of as subsets of $\Bbb N$, this is an injective function from the topology of $X$ into $\Bbb R$.

So if we are given an open covering, $\{V_i\mid i\in I\}$ we may assume that $|I|\leq|\Bbb R|$ by the above consideration, and for each $n\in\Bbb N$ we can look at the set $A_n=\{V_i\mid U_n\subseteq V_i\}$.

Not every $A_n$ is non-empty, but at least one of them is, of course. By the translation between open sets and real numbers, this is reduced to a countable family of sets of reals. Using $\sf AC_\omega(\Bbb R)$ we can choose from each non-empty $A_n$, and we can prove that this is a countable subcover by noting that $\{U_n\mid A_n\neq\varnothing\}$ is an open cover as well.

---

On the other hand, if $\{A_n\mid n\in\Bbb N\}$ is a family of pairwise disjoint sets of reals without a choice function. We may assume that each $A_n$ is a subset of $[n,n+1)$ by using canonical bijections of $[\inf A_n,\sup A_n+1)$ and $[n,n+1)$.

Now consider the open covering of $\Bbb R$ defined by $\{(-r,r)\mid\exists n: r\in A_n\}$. Since the $A_n$'s grow arbitrarily large this is an open covering indeed, so by the assumption it has a countable subcover, which gives for each $A_n$ a countable subset, so by diluting this subcover we may assume that each $A_n$ gives at most a single real number.

And therefore we found a partial choice function for the $A_n$'s. Now it is enough to show that it is indeed enough to consider partial choice functions.

Indeed recall that $\Bbb R^{<\omega}$, the finite sequences of real numbers have the same cardinality as $\Bbb R$ itself. Given a sequence of sets $X_n$ which are non-empty, consider $A_n=\prod_{k\leq n}X_n$, then the $A_n$'s are non-empty sets of finite sequences of real numbers, so by uniform encoding we may assume these are sets of real numbers. If $I\subseteq\Bbb N$ is infinite and $\sigma$ is a function choosing from $\{A_i\mid i\in I\}$, then it defines a choice function from the $X_n$ by looking at $i=\min\{j\in I\mid j>n\}$ and looking at $\sigma(i)(n)$ (recall that $\sigma(i)$ is a choice function which is defined on $X_n$).

Comment: @Mick: I've added the needed part. It's a bit half-assed, but if you need more details let me know.

Comment: @bof: Thanks for pointing out the missing piece.

Comment: So the subcover gives a countable subset of the reals for each $A_n$ by considering $\{r:r\in A_n,(-r,r)\in\text{subcover}\}$, right? What do you mean by «by diluting this subcover»? What is a partial choice function?

Comment: @Mick: No, each $A_n$ is bounded so this set cannot possibly cover $\Bbb R$, but if you take the union over all the $A_n$'s you get a cover (because they live in arbitrarily large $[n,n+1)$ intervals). Then you get a sequence of reals, so pick for each $A_n$ the real with the least index of the countable subcover that appears in $A_n$, if there is such real, there might not be one. But since no single $A_n$ produces a cover, this ensure that we will meet $A_n$ for arbitrarily large $n$, and this gives a choice function for an infinite subset of the $A_n$'s. Hence partial choice.

Comment: OK so let me get this straight. You said we consider the cover of $\mathbb{R}$ formed by the $(-r,r)$ such that $r\in A_n$ for some $n$. I agree it's a cover because the $A_n$'s grow arbitrarily large, since we have assumed WLOG $A_n\subseteq[n,n+1)$. So that is a cover. We assumed a second-countable space is Lindelöf and $\mathbb{R}$ is Lindelöf, thus this cover admits a countable subcover $\{(-r_k,r_k)\}$ for $k\in\mathbb{N}$. I was suggesting we could associate $A_n$ with the set of all $r_k\in A_n$. This maps the subsets $A_n$ to countable subsets. That was my guess to see how the finite …

Comment: … subcover «gives for each $A_n$ a countable subset», as you said. Then you said «by diluting the subcover». Now I can guess this means we only take the $r_k$ with the property that for some $n\in\mathbb{N}$, $k$ is the least integer for which $r_k\in A_n$. Right?

Comment: @Mick: Exactly. And this gives a partial choice, since perhaps we didn't pick any $r_k$ from all the even indexed $A_n$'s?

Comment: Your comment says «this set cannot possibly cover $\mathbb{R}$»: what set? The set $\{r:r\in A_n,(-r,r)\in\text{subcover}\}$? Why would I want it to cover $\mathbb{R}$?

Comment: Ah I see. That's why partial. The countable subcover extraction can prevent us from finding a nonempty set for some $A_n$s, but surely not for all but finitely many. How can I guarantee that?

Comment: Because each $A_n$ is bounded the set $\{(-r,r)\mid r\in A_n\}$ can cover at most the interval $(-n-1,n+1)$ but not more. So you couldn't possibly have chosen from only finitely many. To cover $\Bbb R$ you have to choose from infinitely many distinct $A_n$'s.

Comment: OK I see. What do you mean by «uniform encoding»?

Comment: And one last comment: $\sigma$ is the choice function, so I would see it as $\sigma(A_i)\in A_i$ for all $i\in I$, but of course we can see it as $\sigma(i)$ instead; with that, $\sigma(i)$ is a sequence, and provided $i>n$ we can take its $n$-th term, which is $\sigma(i)(n)$, which will belong to $X_n$, thus giving the desired "total" choice function for the $X_n$'s. So we are done. Thx.

Comment: @Mick: Uniform in the sense that there's no choice needed for each length, and there's no need to choose for each $A_n$ a different encoding. It's all the same encoding. And yes, you got the last part right.

Comment: So this «uniform encoding» is essentially a bijection between $\mathbb{R}$ and the set of all arbitrarily long but finite sequences of reals, which we could view as $\bigsqcup_{n\in\mathbb{N}}\mathbb{R}^n$. Has such a map ever been explicitly constructed?

Comment: @Mick: You can use the bijection between the line and the plane and apply recursively.

Answer (score 3):

The discrete topology on a countable set is second countable; it has a countable base consisting of the singleton sets. Thus, the assertion that all second countable spaces are Lindelöf implies that every cover of a countable set $N$ by subsets of $N$ has a countable subcover. I will show that the latter (ostensibly weaker) assertion implies $\mathsf{AC}_\omega(\mathbb R)$, the countable axiom of choice for sets of real numbers.

Assume that every collection of subsets of $\mathbb Q$ which covers $\mathbb Q$ has a countable subcover. Let $(X_n:n\in\mathbb N)$ be a family of nonempty subsets of $\mathbb R$; I will show that the Cartesian product $\prod_{n\in\mathbb N}X_n$ is nonempty.

For each $x\in\mathbb R,$ let
$$L_x=(\mathbb Q\setminus\mathbb N)\cap(-\infty,x).$$
Now define
$$\mathcal U=\{\mathbb Q\setminus\mathbb N\}\cup\{\{n\}\cup L_x:n\in\mathbb N,\ x\in X_n\}.$$
Since $\bigcup\mathcal U=\mathbb Q$, there is a countable subfamily $\mathcal U'$ of $\mathcal U$ which also covers $\mathbb Q.$ For each $n\in\mathbb N,$ let $U_n$ be the first element of $\mathcal U'$ (relative to some fixed enumeration) which covers $n.$ Then $U_n=\{n\}\cup L_x$ for some $x\in X_n.$ Thus we can define $x_n=\sup(U_n\setminus\{n\})\in X_n$ and we will have $(x_n:n\in\mathbb N)\in\prod_{n\in\mathbb N}X_n.$

Comment: Very interesting alternate way of proving one implication, I'd say easier than Asaf's. Still, I keep his answer as accepted because it is complete :). +1 anyway.

Answer (score -1):

Let $\mathcal B$ be the countable base of $X$. Then for any open cover $\mathcal U=\{U_\alpha:\alpha \in \Omega\}$, then for any $x\in X$ and $x \in U_\alpha$, there exists $B_x\in \mathcal B$ such that $x\in B_x \subset U_\alpha$. Then $\{B_x:x\in X\}$ is the subcover and countable.

Comment: I have the impression this is merely a proof that second countable implies Lindelöf. I am not asking for this proof. I am asking how it can be proved that the proposition "second countable implies Lindelöf" is equivalent to countable choice for subset of the reals, or in short $\mathsf{CC}(\mathbb{R})$, which is what @BrianMScott stated in the comment I linked to in teh question.