# functions that has infinite limit at all points

Tags: real-analysis, limits

> Is there any function $f:\mathbb R\rightarrow \mathbb R$ that has an infinite limit at all points?

There exist functions that are not bounded at any neighborhood at all points. For example
$$f(x)=\begin{cases} n &\text{ for }x=\frac{m}{n}, \text{ for integers } m , n \text{ with }(m , n)=1 , n\neq0 \\ 0 & \text{otherwise.}\end{cases}$$ is a function with the above property. As you see this $f(x)$ is a function that has no limit at any points. It is natural to ask about functions that has an infinite limit at all points.

Comment: Do you mean at any arbitrary point  or at all points?

Comment: You might want to consider that all rationals sufficiently near $m/n$, but not equal to $m/n$ have arbitrarily large denominators. I would agree that you have a function that is not bounded in any neighborhood of $m/n.$ However, *every* neighborhood of $m/n$ also contains an irrational, where your function is $0.$ How do you reconcile that with the requirements for the existence of a limit?

Answer (score 5):

There is no such function.

Proof: For all $N \in \mathbb N$ and for each $y\in \mathbb R$, since $f(x) \to \infty$ as $x\to y$, there is $\delta_y >0$ so that
$$|f(x)|\ge M,$$
for all $x\in \mathbb R$ and $0<|y-x|<\delta_y$. Then

$$\{ ( y-\delta_y, y+\delta_y) : y\in \mathbb R\}$$

forms an open covering of $\mathbb R$, and thus [has a countable subcover](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/81216/every-open-cover-of-the-real-numbers-has-a-countable-subcover-lindel%C3%B6fs-lemma), which we called

$$\{ ( y_n-\delta_{y_n}, y_n+\delta_{y_n}) : n\in \mathbb N\}.$$
As a result, the set
$$\tag{1} \{ y\in \mathbb R : |f(y)|<N\}$$
is countable since it's inside $\{y_1, y_2, \cdots, y_n, \cdots\}$.

But this is impossible, since

$$ \bigcup_{N\in \mathbb N} \{ y\in \mathbb R : |f(y)|<N\} = \mathbb R$$

and $\mathbb R$ is uncountable.

**Remark**: This question is very similar, in essence, to [this](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1801935/does-there-exist-a-function-such-that-lim-x-to-a-fx-l-for-all-a-in) question, and the technique is similar.

**Remark** Another way to show that the set in (1) is countable is by contradiction: if it is uncountable, then [it has a limit point](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/218949/show-uncountable-set-of-real-numbers-has-a-point-of-accumulation) $x\in \mathbb R$. By definition of a limit point, there are $y_n \to x$ so that $|f(y_n)|<N$. But that contradicts to the assumption that $f(y)\to \infty$ as $y\to x$.